# How to read JSON file in phonegap?

Tags: json, cordova

I am using phonegap here.But how to read JSON file ??

```
function readAsText(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  alert("inside readAstext");
  var jsonArray;
  reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    displayContents = evt.target.result;
    alert("assigned");alert(displayContents);
    jsonArray = JSON.parse(displayContents);

  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
  handleResponse(true,jsonArray);
}
```

here evt.target.result is displaying my file in alert as a sting . But once i parse that file I am getting [object object] once inside for loop. How to parse this ? Am i wrong?how to read each content of json here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse a JSON file, you convert it onto an objects, hence your 'alert' is correct. Now that you have an object, simply retrieve the values from the object's properties.

Comment: for(var i in jsonArray) { alert(jsonArray[i].groupId);} is displaying undefined.